# How to customize asp.net DropDownList to support custom data bound field

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any way to customized asp.net dropdown list to support custom data bound filed. it shouldn't be a custom property for the control. it should be able to bind data through `DataBind();` method with the same datasource. in this custom server control i'm trying to access new custom field and based on that value i will do some calculation for that specific row of the data source.

standard control code

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" DataTextField="TextField" DataValueField="ValueField"/>
```

new customized control should looks like this,

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" DataTextField="TextField" DataValueField="ValueField" DataCustomField="CustomField"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could extend DropDownList to something like this:

```
public class MyDropDownList : DropDownList
{
    public MyDropDownList()
    {   
    }

    public string CustomProperty { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in this.DataSource as IEnumerable)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(item);
            PropertyDescriptor pd = properties.Find(CustomProperty, true);
            this.Items[i].Attributes.Add(CustomProperty, pd.GetValue(item).ToString());
            i++;
        }          
    }
}
```

And use it on your markup as follows:

```
<cc1:MyDropDownList ID="MyDropDownList1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Department" CustomProperty="ImageUrl" runat="server">
</cc1:MyDropDownList>
```

On my case, I am binding to a `List<Employee>` with some properties such as `Name`, `Department` and `ImageUrl`. Once the dropdown is rendered looks like this:

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$MyDropDownList1" id="MainContent_MyDropDownList1">
    <option selected="selected" value="Human resources" ImageUrl="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/gal_images/av-_146.jpg">Employee 0</option>
    <option value="Information Technology" ImageUrl="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/gal_images/av-_314.jpg">Employee 1</option>
    <option value="Human resources" ImageUrl="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/gal_images/av-_146.jpg">Employee 2</option>

    <option value="Information Technology" ImageUrl="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/gal_images/av-_314.jpg">Employee 3</option>
    <option value="Human resources" ImageUrl="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/gal_images/av-_146.jpg">Employee 4</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE:** (for @emrahozguner who sent me a question via Twitter on how to retrieve the `CustomProperty` on `SelectedIndexChanged` event)

```
public class MyDropDownList : DropDownList
    {
        public MyDropDownList()
        {
        }

        public string CustomProperty
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string SelectedCustomProperty
        {
            get
            {
                //Use the SelectedIndex to retrieve the right element from ViewState
                return ViewState["CustomProperty" + this.SelectedIndex] as string;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
            int i = 0;
            if (this.DataSource != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in this.DataSource as IEnumerable)
                {
                    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(item);
                    PropertyDescriptor pd = properties.Find(CustomProperty, true);
                    this.Items[i].Attributes.Add(CustomProperty, pd.GetValue(item).ToString());
                    //We need to save the CustomProperty value on ViewState if we want to be able to retrieve it...
                    ViewState["CustomProperty" + i] = pd.GetValue(item).ToString();
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And you access the `CustomProperty` on `SelectedIndexChanged` as so:

```
protected void MyDropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDropDownList l = (sender as MyDropDownList);
        if (l != null)
        {

            string selectedCustomProperty = l.SelectedCustomProperty;
            //Do something cool with this selectedCustomProperty 
        }
    }
```

*Disclaimer:* this is not the only way to do this but it's the simplest I can think of without overriding `LoadViewState` and `SaveViewState`, etc.

Comment: i know that it is rendered as select/option elements on the browser and i just need override that conversion part.then i can use that custom data bound field on DataBind() event.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal: I updated my answer. I think that's what you wanted.

Comment: thanks for the answer. seems it is matching my senario. i will check whether it is working and let you know.